# How to make a progress bar to show cloud function progress on Website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a React/Javascript-Firebase Website where you upload a CSV file, it parses it and uploads it on the firebase database by calling a cloud function.

The cloud function takes a while and is there a way I can show the user the status of my cloud function progress?

Comment: You will have to push your updates to something that the client app can observe, such as a realtime database location.  It's non-trivial to implement.

Comment: You could time your progress bar[1] with the timeout setting of your Cloud Function[2]. 

[1] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-progress-bar-using-javascript/
[2] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout