# Return observable while doing task - Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have a function in my Firebase Cloud Functions that needs to run a scraping task. While the function is scraping the public website I need to return to the consumer a progress feedback. (eg. "Now it's at 10%", "Now it's at 30%", etc...).

I tought using Observables but I get weird results because the scraping function is async but it should return immediately the observable.

This is the simplified code of my **Firebase Functions Backend**:

```js
exports.scrapeFunction = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall((data) => {
 const res$ = new BehaviorSubject<Response>({
  completion: 0,
  completionMsg: 'One moment...',
  error: undefined,
  user: undefined,
 });
 scrape(data.id, res$);
 return res$.asObservable();
});

const scrape = async (id: number, res$: BehaviorSubject<Response>) => {

 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
 const page = await browser.newPage();

 res$.next({
  completion: 10,
  completionMsg: 'I\'m loading the browser...'
 })

 await page.goto('https://example.com');

 res$.next({
  completion: 20,
  completionMsg: 'Page opened...'
 })

 /* Other scraping async functions... */

}
```

On my frontend, instead I've a code similar to this:

```js
response$ = Observable<Response> | undefined;

ngOnInit(): void {
 const scrapeFunction= getFunctions(undefined, 'europe-west2');
 const verifyClient = httpsCallable(functions, 'scrapeFunction');
 const { data } = await scrapeFunction({ id: 0001 });
 console.log('Data is', data);
 this.response$ = (data as any).source as Observable<Response>;
 this.response$.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
 return;
}
```

Logging in the console I get:

```js
Data is 
 {source: {...}}

 source:
  closed: false
  currentObservers: null
  hasError: false
  isStopped: false
  observers: []
  thrownError: null
  _value: {completion: 0, completionMsg: 'One moment...'}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
 [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I also get the following error because the function is not returning an Observable as I know, but an object with the first key "source".

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.response$.subscribe is not a function
TypeError: _this.response$.subscribe is not a function
    at dashboard.component.ts:35:29
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28692:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)
    at zone.js:1276:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
    at zone.js:1120:1
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28692:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)
    at zone.js:1276:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
```

Can someone understand this behavior?

[**UPDATE 1**]

I edited my index.ts file in Firebase Functions to be like this:

```js
const res$ = new BehaviorSubject<Response>({
 completion: 0,
 completionMsg: 'One moment...',
});
exports.verifyClient = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
 scrapeCheck(data.id);
 return verifyClientRes$.asObservable();
});

const scrapeCheck = async (id: number) => {
 await scrape(id, res$);
 res$.complete();
 return;
};

/* The scrape function is actually on an external file */
const scrape = (/* ... */) => {
 /* ... */
}
```

** But i still got the same error on the console.

[**UPDATE 2**]

I created a StackBlitz project. You can find it here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/wherescrypto?file=functions/src/index.ts

The function that is causing this error is in "functions/src/index.ts" and it's called "verifyClient"

Comment: the error talks about iGeniusUserResponse and you didn't provide related code.

Comment: Sorry @AakashGarg I didn't update the error code with the new variable name. this.iGeniusUserResponse is this.response$

Comment: Reviewing some documentation that could help to fix the issue you have, I was wondering if you already considered trying it with a realtime database or firestore.
You'll have to push your updates somewhere, the client app can see them that way.

This solution was mentioned in a comment in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520551/)

Comment: That's ideal @JoseGermanPerezSanchez can you write this answer so I can flag it as the best answer?

Comment: @PietroLungarini thanks a lot, I already posted the answer.
I'm glad that my answer was helpful for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing some documentation that could help to fix the issue you have, I was wondering if you already considered trying it with a `realtime database` or `firestore`.

You'll have to push your updates somewhere, the client app can see them that way. This solution was mentioned in a comment in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520551/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-to-show-cloud-function-progress-on-website).

Answer (score 0):

Putting scrape in setTimeout will do the trick here. so that scrape is invoked after observable is returned.

```
exports.scrapeFunction = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall((data) => {
 const res$ = new BehaviorSubject<Response>({
  completion: 0,
  completionMsg: 'One moment...',
  error: undefined,
  user: undefined,
 });
 setTimeout(() => scrape(data.id, res$));
 return res$.asObservable();
});
```

Comment: It's a bit of a workaround and I don't like it that much but let's try

Comment: yes but in your case if you don't use it it won't return and you are using await and scrape call won't complete until all promises are complete as return type of scrape is Promise<void>

Comment: It doesn't work mate. I still get that weird object instead of the Observable: https://cloud.xsplit.com/c/01G2FPH85VD9DW5CRFFWKRVNH2 (screenshot)

Comment: Now I edited the code a bit. Can you check the original question for the [UPDATE 1]? @aakash-garg

Comment: observable is a object also. try const data = scrapeFunction instead of const {data} = scrapeFunction and you should be able to pipe it. unless return type of functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall is something else

Comment: httpsCallable of Firebase Functions by default returns an object with key { data: any }. Inside data there should be the result of your function @aakash-garg

Comment: then don't do data.source, instead pipe to data directly as data is your observable

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There should not be "source", but there's and it's not an observable. Because if I do response$.subscribe() I get an error saying that response$.subscribe() is not a function. @aakash-garg

Comment: please provide a stackblitz mocking the same

Comment: I already provided all the necessary code. Providing more will be time consuming. Even because it's a lot of code.

Comment: you tried doing response$=data instead of response$ = data.source?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said

Comment: I guess the problem could be that the function terminates after returning the observable, so the scrape function doesn't start at all. Or worse, it starts but it interrupts right away

Comment: setTimeout schedules it in a separate queue (event loop) so scrape will start for sure. interruption depends on logic and debug of scrap function. thats why i asked for stackblitz. if you can't give a mock there let me know and i will remove this answer.

Comment: I just created a StackBlitz. You can check "functions/src/index.ts" (at function called "verifyClient") and "functions/src/igenius/igenius.ts" https://stackblitz.com/edit/wherescrypto-vrayxt?file=functions%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts

Comment: i didn't get from stackblitz what should i check, can you please put some console logs and comments there